# Why my Entity Could not be Saved on DB while JpaRepository.save() Method Returns the Saved Object?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, entity

I am using JpaRepository for db operations in my spring boot application. But when I call the save() method of the dao to save an entity, it doesnt returns null. It returns the saved entity as the result but when I check the database, I saw nothing in the table.

My dao:

```
@Repository
public interface MyDao extends JpaRepository<DataEntity, Long> {}
```

Comment: is there any logs in console ? wrap your code with try catch where you call save method and share logs here

Comment: @isadev41 save method works properly, doesn't throw any error, but it doesnt save

Comment: how are you managing transactions? It is possible the insert does not get commited.

Comment: @MateiFlorescu I am managing like here with transaction manager: https://www.computingfacts.com/post/Multiple-Database-Connection-using-Spring-Data-JPA

Comment: Enable hibernate logs org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG and org.hibernate.type=TRACE. This may give you some hint.